# Not allow add New Page for role 'editor'

Tags: pages, user-roles, capabilities

Sorry for my English first.

What I want to achive is, that it is possible to change existing posts and not possible to add New Posts for the user role "Editor". Is it possible with wp caps or do I need a ugly JS-Hack...  to achive this?

Hi there. Did i missed something? What I've done so far

```
function fsi_remove_addCap() {

        global $wp_roles;
        $wp_roles->add_cap( 'editor', 'create_pages' );
        $wp_roles->remove_cap( 'editor', 'edit_pages' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'fsi_remove_addCap' );
```

Result: It's impossible to edit existing pages too.

Comment: Check out this plugin **https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/**

Comment: Existing posts of the author itself, or all existing posts?

Comment: @PratikPatel: Thanks for your hint. I did. There is a create post cap, but no create page cap. So I think, this will not work for my aims... .